# Android MasterDetail layout inside ActivityTab avoiding nested Fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-actionbar, android-fragmentactivity

I'm not very expert in android's Fragment. In my last project i was using TabActivity, but because of it's deprecation now I'm starting implements an ActionBar using Fragments.

Here is the code of my Tab Class:

```
public class TabInterventoClass extends FragmentActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
            .setText("Dati")
            .setTabListener(new TabListener<DatiFragment_>(this, "dati", DatiFragment_.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = actionBar.newTab()
            .setText("Sistemi alimentazione")
            .setTabListener(new TabListener<SistemaAlimentazioneFragment_>(this, "Sistemi alimentazione", SistemaAlimentazioneFragment_.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = actionBar.newTab()
        .setText("Home")
        .setTabListener(new TabListener<HomeFragment_>(this, "home", HomeFragment_.class));
    actionBar.addTab(tab);
}
```

I've implemented ActionBar.TabListener in this way:

```
public class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private Fragment mFragment;
    private final FragmentActivity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;

    public TabListener(FragmentActivity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
    }

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // Check if the fragment is already initialized
        if (mFragment == null) {
            // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
            // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
            //ft.attach(mFragment);
            ft.show(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment != null) {
            // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
            //ft.detach(mFragment);
            ft.hide(mFragment);
        }
    }
}
```

Please note the comment on attach/detach method in favor of show/hide. This is because in my SECOND tab I get an exception the 2nd time I enter it (surely for bad design of second Tab Fragment). Here the exception:

```
10-18 11:10:13.093: E/AndroidRuntime(3777): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #38: Duplicate id 0xffffffff, tag sistemiList, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for it.cpmapave.mt.ui.intervento.SistemaAlimentazioneListFragment_
```

(Removing the tag and the id of `<fragment android:name="it.cpmapave.mt.ui.intervento.SistemaAlimentazioneListFragment_" />` solve the problem.. but I need a way to get it in order to refresh his adapter! So I show/hide Fragments instead of attach/detach). Luckily I have to fix orientation so I have no problem of overlapping fragments when orientation changes using show/hide.

Here is the FIRST tab display DatiFragment, which extends Fragment class.

[image: First Fragment]

And this seems to be ok!

And here is on the SECOND tab, which displays StrumentiFragment. Here is the layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
android:showDividers="middle">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="center_vertical"
       android:text="Sistema di alimentazione:" />

    <Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/sistemiDiAlimentazione"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

     <Button 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Aggiungi"
        android:id="@+id/addSistemaAlimentazione" />           

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <fragment android:name="it.cpmapave.mt.ui.intervento.SistemaAlimentazioneListFragment_"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:tag="sistemiList"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/item_detail_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Adding an element from Spinner in Fragment A update the FragmentList B. Selecting an element from Fragment List B update details in the Fragment C.

I think the problem could be caused by nested Fragments.. but I don't know how con I design it in a different way.. maybe I make it out to be more difficult than it really is..

I've omitted to say and to show in the code that I'm using ActionBarSherlock, only because I think that is not cause of my problem!

So at the end.. the question is:

**I need to obtain a functional layout like the one showed in the second picture. But I obtained it only by nesting fragments.. I must avoid to do it. How can i do?**

Thank you for any response
Marco

Comment: hide and show in tab activity are bad practice in my case because the fragment doens't be paused and resumed.. so my values are not stored to db..

Comment: I need to obtain a functional layout like the one showed in the second picture. But I obtained it only by nesting fragments.. I must avoid to do it. How can i do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've solved putting each Frame in a FrameLayout, showing/hiding when needed.

I've also defined a custom layout for the class where I created my ActionTab:

```
<TabHost
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+android:id/navtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="600dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+android:id/realtabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="600dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I hope this can be useful for someone!